# Change number output [.] to [,] in pl/sql

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I've function that should change notation of numbers from 12345.67€ to 12345,67€

```
 select

        replace(
    to_char(round(

    123456.789

    ,2),'999G999G999G990D'||substr('0000000000',1,2),'nls_numeric_characters=''.,'''),'.',','
    ) || ' €' 

    from dual;
```

current result is:
123,456,79 €
the result I want to get:
123456,79 €

But I' dont know how. My oracle returns values in format 123456.79 so this is a reason of my calculation. Doe's anybody know what to do?

Comment: For what it's worth - formatting numbers is typically a UI function, not a data layer function.

Comment: Even putting euro symbol at the end is not right, from my point of view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TERRITORY='SWEDEN' for an example. Or Estonia.
Numeric formats are derived from the setting of the NLS_TERRITORY parameter, but they can be overridden by the `NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS` parameter.

Comment: I'm, working on apex, how to do it properely to keep the change on all the time? i dont want problems in my app

Answer (score 1):

You should either set the NLS parameters, if they are not already correct, in the session or in the query e.g.

```
select to_char(123456.789
              ,'9999990D00L'
              ,'nls_numeric_characters='',.'' nls_currency=''€''')
from dual
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select

replace(
to_char(round(

123456.789

,2),'999999999990D'||substr('0000000000',1,2),'nls_numeric_characters=''.,'''),'.',','
) || ' €' 

from dual;
```